# How to write a function (in flutter-dart) so that it accepts certain parameters when we call that function?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

This is my code:

```
Text ButtonText = Text(
  _buttonText, style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: 'San francisco',
    //fontSize: 21.0.ssp,
    letterSpacing: 2.0,
    wordSpacing: 2.0
),
);
```

when I use this Text in my button widget, I want to set font size explicitly. How can I do that?

Comment: Try to create class of TextField as Widget and use that class wherever you wanna set TextField with own parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a class for your situation we can call it customtext
here is an example code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double size;
  final Color color;
  final FontWeight weight;
  
  // name constructor that has a positional parameters with the text required
  // and the other parameters optional
  CustomText({@required this.text, this.size,this.color,this.weight});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,style: TextStyle(fontSize: size ?? 16, color: color ?? Colors.black, fontWeight: weight ?? FontWeight.normal),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's now working as expected. I got the implementation now.